# Transform an improper integral with $\sin,\cos,\ln$ into an equal integral over $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

As there are many properties of integrals and methods of integration often some seem to escape being "readily seen how to...". This is one of the many.
The integral in question is
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\sin x , \cos x) \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{a^{2}}{x^{2}} \right) \, dx = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(\sin x, \cos x) \, \ln\left[ 1 + \frac{(e^{a}-1)^{2}}{4 \, e^{a} \, \sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \right] \, dx.
\end{align}

What are some methods to demonstrate the integral property is true?

Comment: Presumably you say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}$ and then show somehow that $\prod_{n\in\mathbb Z}(1+a^2/(x+2n\pi)^2)=$ that other thing...

Comment: See [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: looks like the weierstrass product expansion for $sin(x)$